# Analogue of Grauert's upper semi-continuity for Bott–Chern cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

In [*Coherent analytic sheaves*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-69582-7), one has the following theorem due to Grauert:

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a holomorphic family of compact complex manifolds with connected complex manifolds $X, Y$ and $V$ a holomorphic vector bundle on $X$. Then for any integers $q, d \geq 0$, the set
$$
\left\{y \in Y: h^{q}\left(X_{y},\left.V\right|_{X_{y}}\right) \geq d\right\}
$$
is an analytic subset of $Y$.

Hence, we can take $V=\Omega^p$ to get the hodge number. I wonder if the above assertion  still holds for $(p,q)$-Bott–Chern cohomology? In other words, for the same conditions, is the set
$$
\left\{y \in Y: h^{p,q}_\text{BC}\left(X_{y}\right) \geq d\right\}
$$a complex analytic subset of $Y$?
Notice that one cannot apply Grauert's theorem to Bott–Chern cohomology, since now we just have the following isomorphism (one can  refer to Demailly's book [*Basic results on sheaves and analytic sets*](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/sheaves.pdf) for more details):
$$
H_\text{BC}^{p, q}(X) \cong \mathbb{H}^{p+q-1}\left(X, \mathscr{L}_{X}^{\bullet}\right).
$$

Comment: You referred to "Demailly's ebook".  I wasn't sure, but guessed that you meant [*Basic results on sheaves and analytic sets*](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/sheaves.pdf).  If that was not correct, please fix it to the correct reference.

Answer (score 5):

The semi-continuity is true for elliptic complexes:
if $(C, d_t)$ is a continuous family of elliptic complexes,
parametrized by $t\in \mathbb R$, the cohomology of $(C, d_t)$
is semicontinuous in $t$. However, Bott–Chern cohomology
are cohomology of an elliptic complex:

M. Schweitzer, [Autour de la cohomologie de Bott–Chern](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3528),
arXiv:0709.3528.

This takes care of semicontinuity in the real analytic setting,
but I suppose you need your jumping loci to be complex analytic.

To see that the jumping loci are complex
analytic, you could use an exact sequence
$$
H^{*}(\Lambda^{p, q-1}(M), \bar\partial)\oplus \overline{H^{*}(\Lambda^{q, p-1}(M), \bar\partial)} \rightarrow
 H_{BC}^{p,q}(M) \rightarrow H^{p+q}(M).
$$
I don't have a citation for this, except my own paper with Ornea,
[Morse–Novikov cohomology of locally conformally Kähler manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0107), Theorem 4.7,
where we proved it for BC-cohomology with coefficients in a local system;
but I suppose it's rather well known. I don't expect that the
theorem that you want (that all jumping loci are complex analytic)
is published anywhere, but this exact sequence is a good starting point.

Comment: Dear @Misha Verbitsky, many thanks for your answer. I still have some doubt looking forward to your reply. Assume the exact sequence you listed is correct, it seems that we still need some exact sequence of the following type ($V_0=V_{r+1}=0)$:$$
0 \rightarrow V_{1} \rightarrow V_{2} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow V_{r} \rightarrow 0$$  to use the property $$
\sum_{i=1}^{r}(-1)^{i} \operatorname{dim}\left(V_{i}\right)=0.
$$ Am I right? Or perhaps you have some another way to go... Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, this argument is not a proof at all, just an idea of a proof; I have a feeling that it would take a whole article to prove it carefully. The vanishing of Euler characteristic won't solve it either, because there are many terms which might jump simultaneously.

Comment: Dear@Misha Verbitsky,
yes, you're right, the only possible one is the short exact sequence, such that $$\text{dim}V_2=\text{dim}V_1+\text{dim}V_3,$$ which is not suitable for our case.